# Trouble with adding lists to a list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, loops

I'm trying to create a list of sub samples (sub_samples) with each sub sample being a list of data points. I want to be able to extract each sub sample from the list using an index. My current result is looking weird:

```
sub_samples <- list()
for (i in (1:n_of_subsamples)){
  data = sample(data_set, 10) #collect 10 data points
  sub_samples=append(sub_samples,as.list(data)) #add it to sub_samples as a list
}
sub_samples[1]
```

There should be 10 data points in each sub sample, but the result from the last line is a single meassurement with a weird-looking index.
I also tried it this way:

```
sub_samples <- c(1:n_of_subsamples)
for (i in (1:n_of_subsamples)){
  data = sample(data_set, 10)
  sub_samples[i]=as.list(data)
}
sub_samples[1]
```

Which gave a similar result.
*the code I included is not concerned with related samples since that isn't the problem and I wanted to make it simpler

Answer (score 0):

We can `sample` the total amount of values that we need and `split` them in groups.

It will be clear with this example.

```
n_of_subsamples <- 5
n_of_each_subsample <- 10

data_set <- 1:100
#set.seed(1678) #For reproducibility. 

sub_samples <- split(sample(data_set, n_of_subsamples * n_of_each_subsample), 
      rep(seq_len(n_of_subsamples), each = n_of_each_subsample))

sub_samples

#$`1`
# [1] 80 60 27 79 63 71 53 36  4 18

#$`2`
# [1]  90  48  91  33   9 100  76  96  12  11

#$`3`
# [1] 52 26 13 94 59 51 83 65 69 81

#$`4`
# [1] 66 15 21 77 98  5 28 16 22 40

#$`5`
# [1] 50 35 57 19 23  1 78 86 29 85
```

This generates 5 groups of 10 values each. You can now use each individual sub sample with `sub_samples[[1]]`, `sub_samples[[2]]` etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer, however there is an issue. When I said that I am not concerned with related subsamples that was for keeping my code simpler in the example. I actually need the subsamples to be unrelated. The solution you're using for the vector (my data is a vector) looks like it would result in related subsamples since it draws 10 random points each time, and I don't know how I can keep track of which data points are already used within the lapply function. Is there a quick way to split a list into a list of unrelated sub-lists?

Comment: @Johnny I think I misunderstood the question earlier. Can you try the updated answer which will split the data in unrelated groups.